# How to write characters such as ">" and "|" to files in batch

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I am trying to write a command to a file so that it can be run in the future.
How do I write the line `netstat -ano | findstr :25565 >pid.txt` to the file `stop.bat`?

Code:

```
echo @echo off> stop.bat
echo netstat -ano | findstr :25565 >pid.txt>> stop.bat
echo FOR /F "usebackq tokens=5" %%%%A in (pid.txt) do (>> stop.bat
echo    taskkill /F /PID %%%%A>> stop.bat
echo    exit /b>> stop.bat
echo )>> stop.bat
```

Output in file "stop.bat":

```
@echo off
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=5" %%A in (pid.txt) do (
    taskkill /F /PID %%A
    exit /b
)
```

Comment: You use the carrot as an escape character to use those special characters as literal characters. `echo ^|^>`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Squashman, fixed it by using `^` before each literal character so`echo netstat -ano | findstr :25565 >pid.txt>> stop.bat` has changed to `echo netstat -ano ^| findstr :25565 ^>pid.txt>> stop.bat` and the file output now reads:

```
@echo off
netstat -ano | findstr :25565 >pid.txt
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=5" %%A in (pid.txt) do (
    taskkill /F /PID %%A
    exit /b
)
```